# Complementary taste to elderberry ice cream?

Tags: flavor

The elderberry ice cream I made turned out a bit too sweet to my taste, so I would like to compensate it with an accompaniment of some sort.

What would be some flavors that I could pair it with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could serve it with a lemon curd tart, making sure to keep down the amount of sugar in the curd. Or just some lemon sorbet, that would also go well I think.

Comment: I ended up using this answer for inspiration and made a lemon sauce. That worked out great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would use yogurt.

First, yogurt dilutes tastes farily well. It has some taste on its own, but it doesn't clash with most aromas you encounter in other dishes (sweet or savory). You can also add it in large amounts without making a dish heavy or changing its character too much.

Second, yogurt goes well with ice cream. I eat the combination even when I don't want to dilute anything, just a cup of ice cream with fruit and yogurt as a dessert. I know I am somewhat biased towards yogurt, but the fact that many gelaterias offer such cups mean that I'm not the only one who likes it.

Third, yogurt is slightly sour (or even very sour, depending on the type you eat), and sweetness and sourness are connected in human taste perception. You can mask large amounts of sugar with enough acid, as evidenced in most soft drinks.

To make it clear, I am talking of pure yogurt here, unsweetened and non-flavored.

Comment: I was going to suggest crème fraîche, but yoghurt is close enough!

Comment: yoghurt and ice cream? Only in Bulgaria...

Comment: @ElendilTheTall quite popular in Italian-owned gelaterias in Germany.

Comment: sounds like a good idea, but I ended up using the lemon suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

One of my friends who is a chef likes to pair sweet things with fresh homemade cheeses like ricotta or mascarpone. It is quite delicious!

Answer (score 1):

A classic flavour pairing for elderberries are gooseberries which have the great bonus of being, when early in their season, very acidic and thus will distract your palette from the sweetness; however, if you just want to reduce the sweetness without introducing any other big flavours, Rumtscho's suggestion of yoghurt would be a better fit.